# How to specify a different delimiter for different column in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

One row of data looks like

```
"!Next?" (1994)                     Italy
```

I need to create 3 columns.

1. Name of the Movie that is enclosed with `""`
2. Date of release that is enclosed with `()`
3. Country where the movie is produced

I need to specify different delimiter for each column.

One IMPORTANT thing - I am loading data from file `/home/ap/Downloads/country.list`

It would be great if could explain a little bit of query along.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not format the file first, so that you can have three column with the same delimiter?

Comment: Its 60Mb file with nearly 20,000 records how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

use this cmd

```
cat YOUR_FILE_HERE|sed 's/"\(.*\)"\s*(\(.*\))\s*\([^\s].*\)/\1^A\2^A\3/g' > OUTPUT_FILE
```

then load this OUTPUT_FILE to your hive table.

REMEMBER:

I use `\001` as delimiter here.If you change the table default fields terminater, use that to replace the `^A` in my cmd.
And also the `^A` is input by `ctrl-v` and then `ctrl-a` not the `^` and `A`.